# chromedriver Only local connections are allowed

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-manager

I try to start tests by webdriver-manager and protractor.

Verify versions:
Google Chrome 73.0.3683.86
ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68

start webdriver-manager `webdriver-manager start`
and start protractor

I got error by protractor

```
enviroment: test
[12:20:23] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[12:20:23] E/driverProvider - Error code: 135
[12:20:23] E/driverProvider - Error message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
[12:20:23] E/driverProvider - Error: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 172 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'dev', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.0-8-amd64', java.version: '1.8.0_212'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at Hosted.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:69:23)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:5:65)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[12:20:23] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 135
```

and info by webdriver-manager

```
12:19:38.934 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "count": 1
}
12:19:38.947 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
Starting ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72) on port 15966
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
```

protractor.conf.js in project folder (where I execute command `protractor --host https://MySite`

```
let test_url = '';
let enviroment = process.env.NODE_ENV;
console.log('enviroment:', enviroment);
//console.log('process.env:', process.env);

let settings = {
        seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
        //directConnect: true,
        specs: ['./e2e/todo-spec.js'],
        // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
        params: {
                host: 'http://localhost:3000'
        },
        capabilities: {
                browserName: 'chrome'
        },
        onPrepare: function() {
            // The require statement must be down here, since jasmine-reporters@1.0
            // needs jasmine to be in the global and protractor does not guarantee
            // this until inside the onPrepare function.
            var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
                new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter('xmloutput', true, true)
            );
        },
        jasmineNodeOpts: {
                showColors: true,
                defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
        }
}
if(process.env.hasOwnProperty('npm_config_host') && process.env.npm_config_host){
        settings.params.host = process.env.npm_config_host
}


exports.config = settings;
```

Comment: This error can happen due to various reasons. Can you post your `conf.js` file. Chrome is starting but is crashing or exiting abnormally.

Comment: Yes, posted it now

Comment: Did you run the webdriver manager update to download the latest binaries. I see you have Chrome 73+.

Comment: Yes, google-chrome is 73 (latest) on linux(xvfb). chromedriver was try both versions 73 and 74.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your chromeOptions, can you try adding `--no-sandbox` and `--disable-dev-shm-usage` and then try running the tests . Also try downgrading the browser version to see if the code is working as expected.

```
"chromeOptions": {
                    "args": ['--no-sandbox','--disable-dev-shm-usage'],
```

Comment: Got same error
`22:19:07.928 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "chromeOptions": {
    "args": [
      "--no-sandbox",
      "--disable-dev-shm-usage"
    ]
  },
  "count": 1
}
22:19:07.931 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
Starting ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72) on port 23495
Only local connections are allowed.`
I was try 74 and 73 vers

Comment: And couldn't find 72 version of google-chrome for linux(xvfb) for try older version

Answer (score 0):

Remove `seleniumAddress:` fomr your config and add the below one.

```
exports.config = {
      directConnect: true,
}
```

When you add `dirctConnect=true` you don't need to start the webdriver separately.

Hope it help you

Comment: This is not a problem with Selenium server not starting. This is an issue with Chrome not being able to start. Please read the stack trace carefully. Your solution is not correct.

Comment: @demouser123 I am sure that i have  read the question before answering.it may not be a actual solution but it is a workaround to fix the problem. I faced the same problem and fixed in this way.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I got another trouble. `Error: WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

in your /etc/hosts file.

To check it, you should go to the terminal and run

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
```

type your user password and paste

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

to an empty row.

Additionally, please make sure you have ChromeDriver -or the driver of the browser you intend to use- is installed and your program knows the path of ChromeDriver.

You can follow the steps explained here https://www.browserstack.com/guide/run-selenium-tests-using-selenium-chromedriver.