# TestNG - ChromeDriver with Chrome version 79 - prevent access by malicious code

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

Please Note before marking this as duplicate: I have already checked and it did not work.

Re-raising this again as my previous post was marked as a duplicate and was closed. The solution provided by the person who marked it as a duplicate did not work.

1. [How do I protect the ports that chromedriver use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55442679/how-do-i-protect-the-ports-that-chromedriver-use)

and

2. [chromedriver Only local connections are allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373740/chromedriver-only-local-connections-are-allowed)

Here is the message that I get when I try to run the TestNG.xml

> Message: [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
>
> Starting ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b3339e8f4d9ed1816f143-refs/branch-heads/394@14}) on port 14625
>
> Only local connections are allowed.
>
> Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.

Windows 10 OS.

Note that I have already tried the following as per the solution provided in other reported issues in Stackoverflow:

1. I am using chrome version 79 and not v73.
2. Downloaded the latest version of the chrome driver for version 79 from this [link](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/)
3. Tried `workaround.bat` with the following text which did not work. `C:\p<>\chromedriver.exe --whitelist-ip %*`

Comment: The correct way to deal with a duplicate closure that you feel is incorrect is not to post a new question, but to edit your previous one, explain why the duplicate closure is incorrect, add additional information that demonstrates it's not a dupe, and get it reopened. This is covered in the [help] in the [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions) section.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only local connections are allowed. Protect ports to prevent access by malicious code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59174613/only-local-connections-are-allowed-protect-ports-to-prevent-access-by-malicious)

Comment: Thank you for the help center links. The other link that you have shared is my own question which was marked as duplicate. I have already updated my previous question with all the details. But looks like, the person who marked it as a duplicate is more interested in diverting users to his solution even though I have clearly mentioned that those steps have been followed.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware it's yours. You need to delete this one and edit that one instead, as I described above and as the links in the [help] describe, exactly as I stated in my previous comment. You *cannot* post a new question instead of properly addressing the old one, as is clearly indicated in the help center.